# SoapClient WSDL cache file names pattern

Tags: php, caching, soap, wsdl, soap-client

When I use PHP SoapClient with WSDL caching enabled, it creates files in temp directory (in my case, in /tmp). Those files names are like:

```
wsdl-someuser-5f2575e302421be10bf5922237f90e34
```

But where do the "someuser" part come from? The script is invoked from CLI by "apache" user, there's no "someuser" in `php.ini` and `php -i` output.

Comment: While I don't have an answer to your question, I did notice that it can be used by any user, not just the one that created it. For example, the 'apache' user will re-use the same wsdl that was cached when the 'root' user retrieved it.